# ERROR in ./src/index.js Module parse failed:Unexpected token (13:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am facing an issue while doing 'npm run build' my react application. Its saying as below:

Error below mentioned:

> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:16)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | } | */
>   | ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));  @
>   multi ./src/index.js Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

**My Application consists of following Snippet and structure**
1) **webpack.config.js** -

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname+'/src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry:[
        './src/index.js'
    ],

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test : /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
        include:__dirname+'/src/', 
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            cacheDirectory:true,
            presets: ['es2015','react','stage-0']
        }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    //path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index_compiled.js',
    path: __dirname+'/dist'
  },
  mode: 'none',

  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

2) **./src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

3)./src/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "root"></div>

   </body>

</html>
```

4)**./src/HelloWorld.jsx**

```
import {React,Component} from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return(
      <div>Hello World !!</div>
     );
    }
};

export default HelloWorld;
```

5) **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reacttuts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Creating React Apps V0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Ashwini kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Upgrade babels - [webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/)  requires babel-loader 8.x | babel 7.x
2. From [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#automatic--loader-module-name-extension-removed):

> It is not possible anymore to omit the -loader extension when referencing loaders

So change in `webpack.config.js`:

```
loader: 'babel',
```

to

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
```

Answer (score 0):

Install **babel-preset-stage-0**

`npm i babel-preset-stage-0 -D`

You are calling it in webpack.config.js

```
 query: {
            cacheDirectory:true,
            presets: ['es2015','react','stage-0']
        }
```

Comment: Installing stage-0 doesn't help even. I tried and I am facing the issue till now

Comment: Please anyone respond to the issue